# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Get product of a specific subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-subscriptions

Is there a way to get from `$product` from `$subscription`?

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791096/woocommerce-subscriptions-get-related-orders-ids-for-a-specific-subscription), I know that from `$subscription` I can get `$order`:

```
$order = $subscription->order;
```

Is this also possible?

```
$product = $subscription->product;
```

Or:

```
$product = $order->product;
```

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to get the products from either the Subscription or the matching order, as a subscription object is an extension of the `WC_Order` class.

```
$subscription_products = $subscription->get_items();
$order_products = $subscription->order->get_items();
```

In most situations where you provide subscription services, both of these will be equivalent or `$order_products` should at least contain all products found within `$subscription_products`.

A notable exception is when you create a subscription manually; no order will be attached to the subscription, so `$subscription->order` may not be a valid `WC_Order` object.

Comment: This helped me tremendously. Specifically `$subscription_products`. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Get product from woocommerce subscription full code with examples of use:

```
if ( sizeof( $subscription_items = $subscription->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $subscription_items as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        //Examples of use
        $product->get_id();
        $product->get_sku();
        $product->get_image('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'alignleft'], false); // main image

        $product_id = wcs_get_canonical_product_id( $item ); // get product id directly from item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you have a "subscription ID" you can get an object like this:

```
$subscription = new WC_Subscription( $the_id );
```

When you already have $subscription object:

```
$related_orders_ids_array = $subscription->get_related_orders();
```

Then loop through array of related orders.

```
foreach ( $related_orders_ids_array as $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
```

then if you loop through order items, you can access product information:

```
    foreach ( $items as $product ) {

        var_dump( $product );

    }

}
```

Comment: The order can have products that are not included in the subscription...

Comment: This is flawed because you will get unwanted orders with it as well