# Output Subscription Number in WooCommerce to use as a Membership Number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I am using WooCommerce with Memberships and Subscriptions. There's two parts to my question. Firstly I am not sure what the best practice is when we want to assign a membership number to a member. A the moment the memberships are assigned to a subscription product so it makes sense to use the subscription product as a member ID. I don't think there's any other option. To that end, I want to output this subscription number as a member ID. There will not be any other subscription products. So the second part of my question is how to print the membership number, something like this:

```
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $subs = wcs_get_users_subscriptions($user_id)
    <em class="mem-num"><?php echo '#'.$subs;?></em>
```

This produces #*Array*

So in actual fact, I probably need to iterate through an array that will only have one value and return it as the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to put together a solution through this answer here: [WooCommerce Subscriptions - Get related orders Ids for a specific subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791096/woocommerce-subscriptions-get-related-orders-ids-for-a-specific-subscription).

```
$customer_subscriptions = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,

        'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', 
        'post_status' => 'wc-active' 
    ) );

            foreach( $customer_subscriptions as $customer_subscription ){
        // The subscription ID
        $subscription_id = $customer_subscription->ID;

                wc_get_order( $subscription_id );

            }

<div class="mem-num"><?php echo '<i class="fas fa-user"></i> Your Membership Number: '.$subscription_id;?></div>
```

I didn't want to get the order number from the subscription ID just to output the subscription ID as the membership number.