# Woo subscriptions - Request not working get_posts()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

My idea is to get all active (status - wc-active) subscriptions.

```
 // Get all active subscriptions
        $active_subscriptions = get_posts( array(
    
            'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // Subscription post type
            'post_status' => 'wc-active', // Active subscription
            'fields'      => 'ids', // return only IDs (instead of complete post objects)
        ) );
```

[image]

But I always get the same result. But the result is not correct.

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(6518) [1]=> int(6514) [2]=> int(6512) }
```

Tried to use this function  **wcs_get_subscriptions()** from a plugin.
Get an error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order() on null ...."

```
// Get all active subscriptions
$active_subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions( array(
    'subscription_status' => 'wc-active'
) );
```

https://github.com/riclain/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/b0dd2efd869b0639ad54131fba9c13b4ed5a09a2/wcs-functions.php#L332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an error like mine that the functions from WordPress (Woocommerce) do not work. You can use SQL.

My solution is this.

```
    function get_active_subscriptions_and_upcoming_renewals() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get active subscriptions
    $active_subscriptions = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT posts.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_subscription' AND posts.post_status = 'wc-active';"
    );

    $active_subs_ids = [];
    foreach ( $active_subscriptions as $active_subs ) {
        array_push( $active_subs_ids, (int)$active_subs->ID );
    }

    $active_subs_string = implode( ',', $active_subs_ids);
// Get subscriptions that will automatically renew after 2 days

    $upcoming_renewals = $wpdb->get_results(

            "
           SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ({$active_subs_string}) AND meta_key = '_schedule_next_payment' AND DATE(meta_value) <= DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY));
            "

    );

    // Return results
    return array(
        'active_subscriptions' => $active_subs_ids,
        'upcoming_renewals'    => $upcoming_renewals,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://github.com/riclain/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/wcs-functions.php#L332), you can see, that the possible options for the `wcs_get_subscriptions` function for parameter `subscription_status` do not include `wc-active`.

> 'subscription_status' Any valid subscription status. Can be 'any', 'active', 'cancelled', 'suspended', 'expired', 'pending' or 'trash'. Defaults to 'any'.

Also note, that the keys in the returned array are the subscription ids, not just integers starting from 0.